# Static Variables In PHP Class

Tags: php

I come from a `C#` background where you can do the below to use the variables repeatedly from any method within the class

```
public class Test
{
  private static servername = "servername";
  private static dbname = "testdb";
  private static username = "username";
  private static password = "password";

  //Any method here could read the values of the static
  //variables that are declared above
}
```

Is there a way to do the same for `php` if multiple calls are being made to the same database with the same user credentials so that the info isn't typed multiple times?

Essentially some sort of re-usable syntax for database calls as opposed to retyping the same 8-10 lines each time I need to query and return results.

EDIT .......
As far as re-usable code goes, I finally found this after much more googling

[http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/simple-php-class-based-querying--net-11863](http://PHP%20Connect%20To%20Database)

Comment: Yes, and it was only one search away from you [in the documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/language.oop5.static.php)…

Comment: Put `$` in-front of the static member names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declaring class properties or methods as static makes them accessible without the need to instantiate the class. A property declared as static can not be accessed with an instantiated class object (though a static method itself can do).

For compatibility with PHP 4, if no visibility declaration is not used, it will be to the properties or methods as if they had been defined as public.

Example:

```
<?php
class Foo {
    public static function staticMethod() {
        // ...
    }
}

Foo::staticMethod();
$name_class= 'Foo';
$name_class::staticMethod(); // Since PHP 5.3.0
?>
```

More information here: http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.static.php